# How to Store article in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, angular

So I just started developing my PWA and it will handle a big chunks of articles. I want that article able to work offline, so I planned to store the article on JSON file.

The thing is the article also have some HTML tag on it like `<ol type="">`. So the `"` is interference with the JSON syntax(?) and made the JSON file error.

There is any solution to store my article in a JSON file and/or any other idea how to store my article?

Comment: you have to escape the quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store html in json you should use escape characters before quotation marks like:

```
let myjson = {
  html: "<h1 class=\"my-classname\">Some text<h1>"
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works well, but the second problem is that the article i want to store is very long, and the JSON file seems "want" the article to be in a single line. Is this still the "good" way to store article or should I try another method to store the article?

Comment: You can store any length of an "article" in a json file. However in my opinion it would be a cleaner approach to store only the data in json, without any html.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the characters by adding `\` before `"`

Like this: `<ol type=\"something\">`